# Using insertAdjacentHTML() to add partial HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation, insertadjacenthtml

I have a very long text wrapped in a single `<p>` tag. like this:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod...
</p>
```

I need to break up that text into smaller paragraph chunks by using javascript or jquery to insert `</p><p>` into certain parts of the text, Effectively ending the last paragraph and then starting a new one (I already have some javascript which identifies where I want to insert the new HTML - that works fine). I've been using insertAdjacentHTML() to add the new paragraph tags:

```
TheElmToInsertNextTo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','</p><p>');
```

**The trouble is:** the browser tries to fix my partial html and keeps wrapping it in additional `<p>` tags like this:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor
<p></p><p></p>
sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod...
</p>
```

As a result: the extra `<p>` tags break my pagination script (from [easyPaginate](https://github.com/st3ph/jquery.easyPaginate)) which otherwise works great.

**Is there a better way to insert partial HTML without the browser "fixing" it by adding additional `<p>` tags?** 
(the issue occurs in both firefox and chrome)

Comment: The HTML has to be converted to DOM elements when you insert it. The DOM can't contain partial elements.

Comment: Construct everything you want to insert as a string in your loop, then insert the whole thing at the end.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for pointing out that this can't be done in the order that I initially thought. I fixed this by pre-processing the data on the server side before loading it into the DOM.